# simplify JSON output from a JavaScript Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

this is my first post. 
I'm quite new to JavaScript Objects and I spent a day trying to figure out but I'm still stuck... I hope someone can give me a tip.

Basically I have 2 or more form that I need to serialize and send data via ajax call.

I have these forms:

```
<form class="lang_block">

    <fieldset>

        <legend>it</legend>

        <input name="language" value="Italiano" type="text">
        <input name="data" value="data_it" type="text">
        <input name="temp" value="temp_it" type="text">

    </fieldset>

</form>

<form class="lang_block">

    <fieldset>

        <legend>en</legend>

        <input name="language" value="English" type="text">
        <input name="data" value="data_en" type="text">
        <input name="temp" value="temp_en" type="text">

    </fieldset>

</form>
```

And and this JavaScript function:

```
function ConvertFormToJSON(target_form)
    {
        var form = $(target_form);

        var arr = [];

        form.each(function()
        {
            var obj = {};

            var sr = $(this).serializeArray();

            obj = $.each(sr, function()
            {
                sr[this.name] = this.value;
            });

            arr.push(obj);
         });

        return JSON.stringify(arr);
    }

    ConvertFormToJSON('.lang_block');
```

The Output :

```
"[
    [
        {
            "name": "language",
            "value": "Italiano"
        },
        {
            "name": "data",
            "value": "data_it"
        },
        {
            "name": "temp",
            "value": "temp_it"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "name": "language",
            "value": "English"
        },
        {
            "name": "data",
            "value": "data_en"
        },
        {
            "name": "temp",
            "value": "temp_en"
        }
    ]
]"
```

The output I'd like to achieve:

```
"[

    {
        "language": "Italiano",
        "data": "data_it",
        "temp": "temp_it",
    },

    {
        "language": "English",
        "data": "data_en",
        "temp": "temp_en",
    }

]"
```

Comment: You're clearly using jQuery, and there's no need to do any of this at all, just call `$('form').serialize()` and send the data with `$.ajax`

Comment: Thanks adeneo but I was trying to do a different thing :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the values on sr instead of the object. Give this a shot:

```
function ConvertFormToJSON(target_form)
{
    var form = $(target_form);

    var arr = [];

    form.each(function()
    {
        var obj = {};

        var sr = $(this).serializeArray();

        $.each(sr, function() {
            obj[this.name] = this.value;
        });

        arr.push(obj);
     });

    return JSON.stringify(arr);
}

ConvertFormToJSON('.lang_block');
```

Comment: Bingo! Thanks rdubya! :)